# How to start the Appium server in iOS machine through Java code

Tags: java, ios, appium

In Windows, I have used the Command line method in Java to open the appium server from Windows 7 machine and that works great. But the same cannot be done in iOS.

**CODE:**

```
public static void startAppiumServer() throws IOException, InterruptedException {   

        CommandLine command = new CommandLine("cmd");
        command.addArgument("/c");      
        command.addArgument("D:\\SOFTWARES\\AppiumForWindows-1.2.4.1\\Appium\\node.exe");  
        command.addArgument("D:\\SOFTWARES\\AppiumForWindows-1.2.4.1\\Appium\\node_modules\\appium\\bin\\appium.js");  
        command.addArgument("--address", false);  
        command.addArgument("127.0.0.1");  
        command.addArgument("--port", false);  
        command.addArgument("4725");
        command.addArgument("--full-reset", false);  

        DefaultExecuteResultHandler resultHandler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler();  
        DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();  
        executor.setExitValue(1);
        executor.execute(command, resultHandler);
}
```

How the same process can be done in iOS Machine. Whether it can be by the Java process runtime execution method or something else?
Suggestions and comments are welcome.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class AppiumServer {

public void startServer() {

    CommandLine command = new CommandLine(
            "/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node");
    command.addArgument(
            "/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/bin/appium.js",
            false);
    command.addArgument("--address", false);
    command.addArgument("127.0.0.1");
    command.addArgument("--port", false);
    command.addArgument("4723");
    command.addArgument("--full-reset", false);
    DefaultExecuteResultHandler resultHandler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler();
    DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
    executor.setExitValue(1);
    try {
        executor.execute(command, resultHandler);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("Appium server started.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void stopServer() {
    String[] command = { "/usr/bin/killall", "-KILL", "node" };
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        System.out.println("Appium server stopped.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```